# Loading JSON Asynchronously on iPhone in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to load JSON from a sever and then display it in a UITableView. The request goes fine however when I try to add the data to the tableview the app crashes when I call then `[tableView reloadData]` method is called. I have the variable `jsonArray` reference in the UITableView methods so that the TableView displays the contents of that variable. Is this the best way to do it and what am I doing wrong?

**The connection**

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

**Main HTTP Callback**

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    //Declare the parser
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    jsonArray = [parser objectWithString:responseString];

    [tableView reloadData];

    [parser release];
    [responseString release];
}
```

**Error**

```
2011-07-07 14:42:56.923 Viiad[16370:207] -[__NSSet0 objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a4a0b0
2011-07-07 14:42:56.925 Viiad[16370:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSet0 objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a4a0b0'
```

**EDIT**

**UITableViewMethods**

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *results = [[jsonArray valueForKey:@"Rows"] valueForKey:@"name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Chances are good that jsonArray is not an NSArray. The app is failing in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Could you post that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message

```
-[__NSSet0 objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a4a0b0
```

means that someplace in the code, the `objectAtIndex:` message was sent to an instance of `__NSSet0`. To me, that looks like you're passing around an `NSSet` where you're expecting an `NSArray`.

Set a debugger breakpoint before you call `[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and see what `results` actually contains. My guess is that the JSON parser isn't returning what you think it is. Objective-C is dynamically typed: just because you say that a variable is  an `NSArray` type doesn't mean it can't contain some other object. If a function returns type `id`, there is no type information for the compiler to check at all.